# Redux callback action

Tags: themes, actions, theme-options, events, framework

I'm very new with [Redux](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redux-framework/). I don't know how to show and hide a textarea using switch (without saving). When my switch turns on, the text input displays and when it turns off, the input hides itself. I tried to use action hook but it didn't work.

Here's my code:

```
Redux::setSection( $opt_name, array(
    'title'     => __( 'Test', 'redux-test' ),
    'id'        => 'switch_buttonset',
    'desc'      => __( '', 'redux-test'),
    'icon'      => 'el el-cog',
    'fields'    => array(
        array(
            'id'       => 'opt-text-email',
            'type'     => 'text',
            'title'    => __( 'Title', 'redux-test' ),
        ),
        array(
            'id'       => 'switch-on',
            'type'     => 'switch',
            'title'    => __( 'Switch On', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
            'default'  => true,
        ),
    )
) );

add_action( 'redux/field/' . $opt_name . '/switch/callback/after', 'compiler_action', 10, 3 );
function compiler_action( $data ) {
    global $opt_name;
    Redux::hideField( $opt_name, 'opt-text-email' );
}
```

Comment: May be a typo but you're missing a `'` single quote in your `desc` value. `'redux-test'`

Comment: Thank @Howdy_McGee for your quick answer, but it's not the problem. Sorry for my mistake in my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but if you are still looking, what you want is the dependency option.

You can use it like this :

```
Redux::setSection( $opt_name, array(
    'title'  => __( 'Test', 'redux-test' ),
    'id'     => 'switch_buttonset',
    'desc'   => __( '', 'redux-test' ),
    'icon'   => 'el el-cog',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'id'      => 'switch-on',
            'type'    => 'switch',
            'title'   => __( 'Switch On', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
            'default' => true,
        ),
        array(
            'id'         => 'opt-text-email',
            'type'       => 'textarea',
            'title'      => __( 'Title', 'redux-test' ),
            'dependency' => array(
                'element' => 'switch-on', //Name of the field that will hide or show this one
                'value'   => array( 'true', 1 ) //The value it should have for it to be displayed
            ),
        )
    )
) );
```